# SWIFT 3: Match different array of sound files to each each section in CollectionView

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, audio

Using Swift 3

I have set up a collectionView with 7 sections - when user taps a cell(button) a specific sound will play from an array of sounds.

So how do I split up the sections in the collectionView to match a specific array of sounds?

for instance

1) sounds in soundArray1 will play when users tap cells(buttons) in section 1 of collectionView

2) sounds in soundArray2 will play when users tap cells(buttons) in section 2 of collectionView

3) sounds in soundArray3 will play when users tap cells(buttons) in section 3 of collectionView

all the way up to section 7.

Here is the current code when user taps cellButton

```
func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
    return sections.count
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

    if section == 0 {
        return self.appleProducts.count

    } else if section == 1 {
        return self.animals.count

    } else if section == 2 {
        return self.food.count

    } else if section == 3 {
        return self.activity.count

    } else if section == 4 {
        return self.travel.count

    } else if section == 5 {
        return self.objects.count

    } else if section == 6 {
        return self.symbols.count

    } else {
        return 0
    }
}

func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell

    if indexPath.section == 0 {
        cell.cellButton.setTitle(appleProducts[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)

    } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        cell.cellButton.setTitle(animals[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)

    } else if indexPath.section == 2 {
        cell.cellButton.setTitle(food[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)

    } else if indexPath.section == 3 {
        cell.cellButton.setTitle(activity[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)

    } else if indexPath.section == 4 {
        cell.cellButton.setTitle(travel[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)

    }  else if indexPath.section == 5 {
        cell.cellButton.setTitle(objects[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)

    } else if indexPath.section == 6 {
        cell.cellButton.setTitle(symbols[indexPath.row], for: UIControlState.normal)
    }

    cell.cellButton.tag = indexPath.row

    return cell
}

@IBAction func cellButton(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    let sound =  (sender as! UIButton).tag
    self.setupAudioPlayer(file: Sounds[sound] as NSString, type: ".m4a")
    self.soundPlayer.play()
}
```

where Sounds is array 1 of sound files. However this array of sound files is playing across all sections of the collectionView right now. I can't work out how to split each array of sounds to match each section in the collectionView

Comment: Use `indexPathForItem(at point: CGPoint) -> IndexPath?` (using the `centre` of the button as the point) and then use the `indexPath.section` to determine which array to select from (using `indexPath.row`).

Comment: there doesn't seem to be a function indexPathForItem? closest is didSelectItemAt indexPath

Comment: See [here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uicollectionview/1618030-indexpathforitem).

Comment: thank you - could you give a small bit more detail - for instance is indexpathforitem a standalone function or within my my cell button action code? what i mean is where is best place to put these functions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `collectionView` method `indexPathForItem(at point: CGPoint)` to get the correct index path.  Something like this:

```
func didPressBtn(sender: UIButton) {
    let point = sender.center
    let cvPoint = self.collectionView!.convert(point, from: sender.superview)
    let ip = self.collectionView!.indexPathForItem(at: cvPoint)!        
    print("Button \(ip.section):\(ip.row) pressed")
    // You can then use ip.section to decide which array to use
    // and ip.row to choose the correct element from the array.  Like this:
    if (ip.section == 0) {
        self.setupAudioPlayer(file: soundsArray1[ip.row] as NSString, type: ".m4a")
        self.soundPlayer.play()}
    } else if (ip.section == 1) {
        self.setupAudioPlayer(file: soundsArray2[ip.row] as NSString, type: ".m4a")
        self.soundPlayer.play()}
    } else if (ip.section == 2) {
        self.setupAudioPlayer(file: soundsArray3[ip.row] as NSString, type: ".m4a")
        self.soundPlayer.play()}
    } // etc etc 
}
```

Regarding the "Ambiguous reference to member" error, I had assumed in the above code that you were either using a `UICollectionViewController`, which has a `collectionView` property, or had created a `collectionView` property in a `UIViewController`, to reference the collection view.  To add one (or check it), you should have

```
@IBOutlet var collectionView : UICollectionView!
```

in your class definition.  Then in the storyboard, you need to link the collection view in the relevant scene to your view controller.  To do this, ctrl-drag from the view controller icon (yellow circle) at the top of the scene to the collection view.  When the prompt appears, select "collectionView" from the list of outlets:

[image]

You can check whether the link has been established in the Connections Inspector in the right hand pane:

[image]

Comment: func indexPathForItem(at point: CGPoint) -> IndexPath?{
    
        if indexPath.section == 0{
            return Sounds[indexPath.row]
        
        } else if indexPath.section == 1 {
        
        
        }
    
        return nil
    }

Comment: this is the function I have set up so far but getting lots of errors

Comment: sorry - very new to swift so the more detail the better - thank you!!

Comment: @GuydeBromhead No need to implement that function (`indexPathForItem(at:)`): the collectionView already has that method.  Just use it much as I do in the code above.  I'll expand it to show exactly how to get the correct sound playing.

Comment: awesome thanks - Im getting one final error based on this code - at this line

Comment: let cvPoint = self.collectionView!.convert(point, from: sender.superview)

Comment: the error is saying 'Ambiguous reference to member 'collectionView(_:numberOfItemsInSection:)'

Comment: Check the code carefully - you might have `(` where there should be `.`

Comment: let cvPoint = self.collectionView!.convert(point, from: sender.superview)

Comment: it seems to be ok - this is the only error stopping me from moving forward!! Haha been trying to work this out for a couple of weeks now

Comment: could you please give me any advice that would be helpful to solve this error? It seems that I am very close to solving this - just the error above is stopping me from moving forward. Thank you

Comment: Sorry, not at my Mac just now - will look into it later.

Comment: thank you for your help - if you need any other batches of code I have already written that might help solve the last error let me know! thanks again - really appreciate help

Comment: @GuydeBromhead In your storyboard, are you using a UIViewController, or a UICollectionViewController?  If the former, check you have hooked up the collection view to the `collectionView` property of the VC.

Comment: yes using a UIViewController and placed a collectionView inside the viewController - pretty sure its all hooked up

Comment: it all seems to be working fine apart from the above line of code that I have pointed out

Comment: @GuydeBromhead I can't see why you are getting that error.  Please can you edit your post to include the full code for the view controller containing the collection view?  Thanks

Comment: added all the collection view functions to the above code

Comment: @GuydeBromhead I only get the error to which you refer if I comment out my IBOutlet collectionView property - are you sure that's in place?

Comment: oh right ok - how do I check exactly if that is in place?

Comment: thank you VERY VERY MUCH - that solved the issue!! Legend!!

Comment: 3 weeks of trying to figure it out!! Thanks again!!